# Web Bluetooth API get list of all available device nearby

Tags: google-chrome-extension, bluetooth, browser-extension, bluetooth-gatt, web-bluetooth

I am looking for an API call that could be used to retrieve all the Bluetooth devices near me. These samples [Web Bluetooth](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/) talk about getting different characteristics from a single Bluetooth device, however I couldn't find any example which retrieves all the Bluetooth devices(like available bluetooth devices list on windows native Bluetooth app). Is it even supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally haven't experimented with Web Bluetooth API a lot, but I think you're looking for [Device Discovery](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#device-discovery) and [Request Bluetooth Devices](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web#request_bluetooth_devices):

> This version of the Web Bluetooth API specification allows websites,
>   running in the Central role, to connect to remote GATT Servers over a
>   BLE connection. It supports communication among devices that implement
>   Bluetooth 4.0 or later.
>
> When a website requests access to nearby devices using
>   navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice, Google Chrome will prompt user with
>   a device chooser where they can pick one device or simply cancel the
>   request.
>
> The navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice function takes a mandatory
>   Object that defines filters. These filters are used to return only
>   devices that match some advertised Bluetooth GATT services and/or the
>   device name.

Also, here's the list of [GATT
Services](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services).

Answer (score 2):

<sup>(Well, this question sent me down a rabbit hole...)</sup>

It's a couple years later and we're starting to signs of life from `api.Bluetooth.getDevices`. I eventually got an experimental demo working in Chrome.

You'll probably need to enable Chrome's "Web Bluetooth experiment".  (Firefox has an equivalent but I didn't try it.)

1. Go to `chrome://flags/` then search for `bluetooth` and enable the API.
2. Click the buttons on the demo page: [Web Bluetooth / Get Devices Sample](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/get-devices.html)

---

**Demo code** from the same page:

```javascript
function onGetBluetoothDevicesButtonClick() {
  log('Getting existing permitted Bluetooth devices...');
  navigator.bluetooth.getDevices()
  .then(devices => {
    log('> Got ' + devices.length + ' Bluetooth devices.');
    for (const device of devices) {
      log('  > ' + device.name + ' (' + device.id + ')');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    log('Argh! ' + error);
  });
}

function onRequestBluetoothDeviceButtonClick() {
  log('Requesting any Bluetooth device...');
  navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
 // filters: [...] <- Prefer filters to save energy & show relevant devices.
    acceptAllDevices: true
  })
  .then(device => {
    log('> Requested ' + device.name + ' (' + device.id + ')');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    log('Argh! ' + error);
  });
}
```

*Good luck!*

Answer (score 1):

A [Web Bluetooth Scanning](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/scanning.html) specification draft exists, but [implementation isn't started](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/gh-pages/implementation-status.md#scanning-api) anywhere as of 2018.